# Why does my program print the method before the variable?

Tags: java

When I run this program:

```
class Baap {
    public int h = 4;

    public int getH() {
        System.out.println("Baap " + h);
        return h;
    }
}
public class Beta extends Baap {
    public int h = 44;

    public int getH() {
        System.out.println("Beta " + h);
        return h;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Baap b = new Beta();
        System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());
        Beta bb = (Beta) b;
        System.out.println(bb.h + " " + bb.getH());
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Beta 44
4 44
Beta 44
44 44
```

If you look carefully at the first `System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());`, doesn't this command tell Java to print out the value of h before the value of the getH() method?
Shouldn't the first part of the printout be `4` instead of `Beta 44`?

Comment: your class name is superb :D

Answer (score 6):

Before `println` is called, its argument - `b.h + " " + b.getH()` - is evaluated. During that evaluation `Beta 44` is printed due to the call to `getH()`. Only after the evaluation, `println` is passed the result of the evaluation (`4 44`) and prints it.

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't the first part of the printout be 4 instead of Beta 44?

No because calling `getH()` first calls

```
System.out.println("Beta " + h);
```

*then*

```
return h;
```

which then allows the rest of the calling line

```
System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());
```

to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

No wath you see in the consol is right. Wath happens ther? You got a classical side effect.
Java evaluates all Arguments from the left to the rigth. 
When i comes to the b.getH() Method it calls the method. 
In Beta.getH() ther is the Line "System.out.println("Beta " + h);"
So this happens. After That getH() returns 44. Now the String Concationation is computed and then println("4 44") gets called.